# How does Mercurial handle components or modular development?

Tags: svn, mercurial, cvs, components

Using CVS at the moment...

When creating a new project that references modular components we use aliases to put together a project directory. So, if `project1` uses `component1` and `component2` then we'd use aliases to pull these components into the `project1` directory so that

```
cvs co project1
```

Would give the developer all they need - with the components in sub-directories.

I understand the equivalent in Subversion is `svn:external`, but could be wrong.

My question is how does this work with Mercurial? I've heard folks talk about the Forest Extension and various other modules but I'd have expected this sort of functionality to be pretty core (so I'm assuming I've missed something).

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217523/can-i-emulate-svnexternals-using-mercurial), but I don't think this is a duplicate.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mercurial had no official way to do this until the 1.3 release.  Now it has [sub repo](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/subrepos) support.  It's still considered experimental, but it was implemented from whole cloth by Mercurial's creator and he's a sticker for backward compatibility, so you're not likely to be left high and dry.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [DepsExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/DepsExtension) for Mercurial that can be used for similar purposes as svn:external.

Comment: Hi. I'd seen this, but was a little worried that it wasn't part of the core Mercurial offering. It feels like pretty much core functionality of any development project so assumed.

Comment: I failed to parse your second sentence, sorry. Note however that a lot of Mercurial functionality is distributed in the form of extensions.

Comment: If an extension isn't distributed with mercurial I wouldn't count on it staying current.  For a small project or personal use you might consider it, but I'd not stake my company's build on a 3rd party extension.