# What are the best and must-have hg / mercurial extensions?

Tags: mercurial

I've been dabbling with hg / mercurial lately, namely in conjunction with Fogcreek's Kiln, and I'm trying to figure out what the must-have extensions are.  Its a little tricky sifting through their extension list because I'm not interested in testing any buggy or impractical extensions, even if their description sounds awesome.

So, which hg extensions do you use?

See [Using Extensions](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UsingExtensions)

Comment: Probably NOT "deps" - my initial testing makes it seem too buggy/new to use

Comment: To the list I'd also add [task extension](https://bitbucket.org/alu/hgtasks/wiki/Home) to manage "coding tasks" and [prompt extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PromptExtension) to show repository info on the shell prompt. Prompt can use the task extension. Them both are not shipped with hg.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

My own hit list:

The simple ones you must have:

1. `color`: colorize output from commands like `diff` and `status`, which makes it easier to assess.
2. `pager`: browse long output a page at a time.
3. `fetch`: pull, update and merge from another repo in one step.
4. `graphlog`: display revision graphs in your shell, incredibly useful for looking at the branches in your log history.
5. `hgk`: browse the repository with a graphical interface (see also TortoiseHg and Murky)

If you enable `pager`, you should configure it to not interfere with certain commands:

```
[pager]
pager = LESS='FSRX' less
ignore = version, help, update, serve, record
```

The intermediate extensions I highly recommend (and use frequently):

1. `record`: lets you interactively select hunks of files to commit - perfect for when you are in the middle of one set of changes, and you end up fixing something that should have its own commit.
2. `extdiff`: configure an external diff tool (such as meld)
3. `share`: have multiple clones use the same repo history

The Advanced extensions I would not be without:

1. `mq`: manage a stack of patches. Very powerful, allows layering of patches on top of the tree.
2. `notify`: send email notifications when a repo is changed.
3. `rebase`: reapply local changes on top of a new parent revision.
4. `largefiles`: work with large binary files outside the hg store

All the above are bundled with Mercurial, and are stable and well-tested.  I highly recommend all of them.

Non-core extensions worth investigating:

1. `shelve`: selectively put aside changes (at the granularity of hunks) and restore them.
2. `acl`: selectively allow access to different parts of the repository tree

Superseded extensions and migrated to core (info from @durin42):

- `forest` was been superseded by the `subrepo` support introduced in v1.3
- `bookmarks` is in core and always enabled
- `transplant` is superseded by `graft`, a core command
- `histedit` is in core as of v2.3, but is disabled by default
- `inotify` is not recommended, as there is apparently a bug due to a race condition

Comment: Any other comments on Subrepo vs. Forest?  I'm not positive that either of them are actually useful/usable - which might imply I'm just 'doing it wrong.'  I'm particularly interested in a robust improvement to SVN's 'extern'

Comment: color does not work on Windows (http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue1579)

Comment: @JJBigThoughts: I have recently started to experiment with subrepo support, with a view to using it for a very large project. According to the Mercurial authors, subrepo support is still somewhat experimental.  Currently it works much like svn:externals, but only a few commands know about subrepos. The basics seem to work well, AFAICT. The main difference is that the version of each subrepo is effectively pinned, as the parent stores a reference to its revision number as well as location (which isn't necessarily a bad thing).

Comment: @Jerome The colour extension seems to work fine in Cygwin.

Comment: How about patchbomb? I find it very handy, at least when you do open source stuff and review happens via mailing list.

Comment: @tonfa: sure, patchbomb looks very useful; I just haven't tried it yet so I can't recommend or comment on it.  On a related note, the extensions that Google developed for Go source reviews via Reitveld look very interesting.

Comment: @Jerome color extension in ANSI mode + tpager are working fine for me on Windows (tpager can be fount on Bitbucket and CodePlex)

Comment: color has been fixed in mercurial 1.6

Comment: histedit is part of the latest hg release (2.3), bigfiles became largefiles and is also now part of the tree (since at least 2.2, but maybe earlier). I'd be a little wary of inotify - it sometimes has races that result in weird status output. transplant is superseded by the core 'graft' command (which is smarter). Starting in 2.1 (I think) bookmarks are always on.

Comment: @durin42 I updated the answer based on comments here and in the recent HN article. Please let me know if there's anything I missed or needs updating.

Comment: Create an [awesome list](https://awesome.re) with this inside! :) There's [one for git](https://github.com/stevemao/awesome-git-addons). I don't use mercurial much, but looks like there's plenty of good things for mercurial too!

Comment: These from your list are marked as **deprecated**: `fetch`, `graphlog` and `record`. Saw this using `hg extensions help`

Answer (score 9):

`graphlog` and `mq` are especially tasty.

1. Convert: convert to and from other systems
2. Mq (Mercurial Queues): deal with changes as a stack of patches
3. Forest: lets you commit to and update many nested Mercurial repositories at once
4. Share: to save time and disk space when working with similar repositories
5. Hgk: gives a graphical view of history
6. Graphlog: I always type 'hg glog' not 'hg log'. An ascii art view of history
7. Transplant: Useful when you only want to merge a few changesets from another branch. The newer `hg rebase` may have some overlap.
8. Rebase: A different way to deal with changes as a set of changesets on top of a branch. `git` users like to rebase. May replace `mq` for many use cases.
9. Shelve: A place to stash the working copy's changes if you have to work on something else for a while.
10. Bookmarks: Name the newest commit on a particular branch. Similar to `git` branches.

Comment: graphlog is now built-in and always enabled with `-g` for the log command (and incoming an outgoing IIRC).

Comment: Ry4an: "now" meaning in tip? Not in 1.4.1 AFAICT.

Comment: The `-g` flag for log is to enable git style diffs, which is completely different from `graphlog`.

Comment: My error.  It's `-G` to get a graphlog out of graph, but you still need the extension enabled for now.

Comment: you can also add `progress` extension

Answer (score 9):

Not yet mentioned: mercurial_keyring

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeyringExtension

"Keyring extension uses services of the keyring library to securely save authentication passwords (HTTP/HTTPS and SMTP) using system specific password database (Gnome Keyring, KDE KWallet, OSXKeyChain, dedicated solutions for Win32 and command line)."

I use ssh to access my repos on GitHub and Bitbucket, and my keyphrase is held in the keychain. This extension lets Mercurial get it whenever needed.

Also required for me: hg-git

http://hg-git.github.com/

Mercurial plugin letting you pull and push git repos using hg as a client. Use it all the time.

Answer (score 7):

If you're working with a slowish host like Bitbucket, [progress](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ProgressExtension) is essential. Otherwise `hg push` looks like it's hung :\

Answer (score 1):

My list:

1. graphlog.  I use it much more than hg log.  (wish it could restrict to branches)
2. purge. remove all files not in Mercurial.  I use this instead of or as a cleaner version of make clean.

Less used, but nice:

- children (lets you say "hg children -r XXX")
- parentrevspec: lets you say stuff like "foo~2 = foo^1^1 = foo^^ = first parent of first parent of foo"

I keep trying to use the history editing tools, but keep running into limitations. I *want* them to work.

- collapse
- histedit
- I consider rebase a history editing tol as well

By the way, beware: hgk and fetch are "unloved": https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UnlovedFeatures.  But then, SubRepos are, not unloved, but a feature of last resort, and I use subrepos.