# what is the best practice for external repos in hg?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Similar, but the answer is discouraged by hg docs: [Can I emulate svn:externals using mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217523/can-i-emulate-svnexternals-using-mercurial)

Prior to using hg I was using Subversion. It seems like the externals in Subversion are quite strong: I can have sub-repo that is pointing to a specific version of another repo. But the docs for [Subrepository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) in Hg say it is a 'Feature of Last Resort'. Wow that's ominous. Plus I don't see anything in the docs about sticking that subrepo to a specific version.

Deps extension is no longer maintained.

Forest extension is discouraged on the site.

So if I want version XYZAB of a repo to be nested inside my Hg repo, what's the best alternative right now that isn't a Feature of Last Resort? Is Hg just kinda bad at this feature?

Guestrepo is worth looking at, but very new at this point: https://bitbucket.org/selinc/guestrepo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the docs for Subrepository in Hg say it is a 'Feature of Last Resort'. Wow that's ominous.

This means that you should double-check that you really need subrepos. There are many very large project that use Mercurial without using subrepositories. They manage their code as a collection of loosely-coupled repositories instead — the main problem with subrepositories is that they create a [very tight coupling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8637556/110204) and tightly coupled components are normally avoided in software design since they restrict your flexibility.

However, support for subrepositories *wont* go away, infact it will gradually improve over time as people present good use cases to us.

> Plus I don't see anything in the docs about sticking that subrepo to a specific version.

Strange, since subrepositories are all about checking out a specific version. That is, you can **only** checkout the exact same version that you committed. The version is written to `.hgsubstate` when you commit and `hg update` will consult that file on checkout.

Please see the [Mercurial Kick Start guide](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/#another-version) and [`hg help subrepos`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#subrepositories) for info about how the `.hgsubstate` file is treated.